# Using NTPD on OpenBSD to get time from Linux using portforwarding

Tags: ntp, openbsd, pf, ipfw

This is a rehash of [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/207746/setting-up-ntp-on-2-linux-boxes-and-one-openbsd-box), now that I understand things a bit better.

I have the following network set up:

```
    NTP
  10.21.3.169
    |     \______________
    |                    \
  10.21.3.160 (eth1)     |   
   L1                    |
  10.0.0.67 (eth0)       |
    |                    |
    |                    |
  10.0.0.65 (pcn1)       |
   OpenBSD               |
  10.0.0.51 (pcn0)       |
    |                    |
    |                    |
  10.0.0.49 (eth1) 10.21.3.159 (eth0)
                 L2
```

Where L1 and L2 are Linux boxes.

I would like the OpenBSD box to be able to get the time from the NTP server. I have been told that to achieve this I need to make some changes to the OpenBSD box's `/etc/pf.conf` file.

My initial attempt is as follows. I know I will also need to make some changes to iptables on the Linux box, but for the moment `tcpdump udp` on the Linux box doesn't show any traffic coming through from the OpenBSD box, I'm assuming that the NTP client's request isn't being properly routed to the Linux box.

```
rdr on pcn1  proto udp from any to any port 123 -> 10.0.0.67
nat on pcn0 proto udp from any to 10.0.0.67 port 123 -> pcn1
```

I am updating the OpenBSD box's configuration with the following command:

```
pfctl -F all ; pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

And I am doing the ntp update with the following command to see what happens:

```
ntpd -d -s
```

I am using 'traditional' ntp, not OpenNTP.

What do I need to change in pf.conf to see UDP packets arriving on L1? Just to reiterate, the PF configuration is on the same machine that I will be running the ntpd client on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it working. First of all, the pf configuration is:

```
rdr on pcn0    proto udp from any to any port 123 -> 10.0.0.67
nat on pcn0 proto udp from any to 10.0.0.67 port 123 -> pcn1
```

But also, I had configured my ntp client to connect to `10.21.3.169`, and in fact it should be connecting to `10.0.0.67`.

I now need to configure the machine listening at 10.0.0.67 to forward NTP requests on to 10.21.3.169, but that's a subject for another question! :)